htmx Pusherapp Websockets
hosted Websocket provider: https://pusher.com/
I'd like to use Pusher hosted WebSocket's with HTMX. It'd be great if I could us the Websocket extension or I can just use write some customer shim code to parse the message body and process like it was an html page.
How can this be done. I was looking at the htmx api process, but it looks like I would have to do some additional processing on the message body to determine to the elements i needed to replace. How can I hook in to htmx native DOM processing
update:
I can use the HTMX javascript api html.swap()...
Example"
htmx.swap("#id_to_swap",'Content to swap','outerHTML');
I'd like to have the WebSocket body just me the raw html to process, jut like it was coming back from the server as a get/post.
to keep my server response basic, I'd have to parse the html coming back from the web socket. This is logic that HTML already has, there must be a way to hook into it
